# Vmware workstation 7 guest can't see internet (host-only networking)

Tags: networking, debian, vmware-workstation

I installed Debian 6 on VMware Workstation running on a win 7 host. I set the network adapter to host-only because I want the guest VM for my personal dev machine accessible only by myself.

I've set up VMware virtual network apapter with a DHCP server running its own subnet and the guest is assigned its IP address OK - I can log into the guest with Putty from the host.

However when I try to ping an internet address from the guest, there's no reply. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I set the network adapter to host-only

Well there's your problem. Network traffic will not be able to leave the host. You'll need to choose bridged or NAT mode to allow your VM to contact internet hosts.

Comment: I found this article http://blog.sourcehosting.net/2008/03/17/vmware-host-only-network-outbound-connections/ which describes a setup that would support having an active internet connection from the guest OS but it looks quite complicated.